# AuthorizeAttribute only called once

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

Hee guys,

I have made my own custom athorizeattribute. It only fires once (directly after the first actionresult that has this attribute). But when I try to go to that same action it works (which can lead to a security breach).

Controller:

```
[AuthenticationController.IsLoggedInAsHero]
public ActionResult Hero()
{
    return View();
}
```

AuthenticationController:

```
    public class IsLoggedInAsHero : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!isAuthenticatedAsHero())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                            new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" })
                                    );
            }
        }
    }
```

isAuthenticatedAsHero():

```
public static bool isAuthenticatedAsHero()
{
    User user = new User();
    user = udc.GetUserByCookie();
    if (user.Hero== 1 && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    { return true; }
    else return false;
}
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "But when I try to go to that same action it works"? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Haha sorry, I think I messed up there. So the first time I get denied, and the second time I get approved (with same user info) as where I should both be denied access.

Comment: Looks like it depends on the implementation of isAuthenticatedAsHero() function, isn't it? can you share this function?

Comment: Question has been updated with the function.

Comment: It it worked first, it should work next time also. In your `IsLoggedInAsHero` attribute, are you able to hit breakpoint at `if (!isAuthenticatedAsHero())` statement? Probably the user is already authenticated?

Comment: From the method name GetUserByCookie(), am assuming that you are getting the user object by request cookie. Why are you storing user information in cookie?

Comment: Have you read the msdn documentation on AuthorizeAttribute and the other methods it exposes with base implementation? I think you may be confused with when HandleUnauthorizedRequest is triggered by default.

Comment: @KrishnaChaithanyaMuthyala I wouldnt know how to store user information otherwise, and retrieve it with a web request. I want to divide my website into two sections: heroes and non heroes. Hero's cant only access pages with the [....IsLoggedInAsHero] attribute. Is this the wrong way?

Comment: any luck @kraishan ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is your solution, but as far as I think, you should override this method:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext){
    return isAuthenticatedAsHero();
}
```

**and**

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                 new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" })
                             );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want my authentication to be dynamic, so I also want to be able to handle multiple forms of roles (e.g: Heroes and Villains). Your solution will not allow that as it returns isAuthenticatedAsHero().

Answer (score 1):

It is better to let the base class to handle the unauthorized requests which then it would return a 401 status code if user is unauthorized. Then ASP.Net framework checks if your website has forms authentication enabled and in turn it will automatically redirect to the login page.

Therefore your IsLoggedInAsHero class should look like this

```
public class IsLoggedInAsHero : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
       protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
       {
            if (!isAuthenticatedAsHero())
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
       }
    }
```

And you need to enable form authentication in your web.config file.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
 </authentication>
```

Comment: This would be ok if you were pushing everything to re-login every time they tried to access something they weren't. But what if you wanted to send it to an error page or pop-up a message explaining their limited access? Op's head is in the right direction, I even included code below that will help facilitate what they are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In most of my systems I have a segragated area for users usually dubbed the "Dashboard". Here is my example for authorization for that:

```
 public class DashBoardAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the unauthorized request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            var newName = "UserContext" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            var cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            var userContext = cache.Get(newName) as IUserModel;
            if (userContext != null && !userContext.DashBoardAccess)
            {
                var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);
                var address = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home");
                context.Result = new RedirectResult(address ?? "login");
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

And on my controller or at the indiviual action:

```
[DashBoardAuthorizeAttribute]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUsers(){
 return View();
}
```

This will execute before any action is executed every single time. You should re-evaluate your naming convention in future projects. If I were an other developer hired to help you on this project, I would have no idea what "IsLoggedInAsHero" is or supposed to do unless I opened the code and looked at it. The naming convention should convey at a basic what it is and supposed to do for ease of development. With "DashBoardAuthorizeAttribute" another developer can assume that its an Authorization Attribute pertaining to a "Dashboard".

Comment: Thanks for replying. But isn't that what I already have? An authorizeattribute and an overidden handleunauthroizedrequest? I am not using ASp.NET authorization by the way, not sure if that's an issue.

Comment: Do you have your attribute on top of every action? Or is it at the top of the controller? If you put it on the top of the controller it will fire for every single action that hits, each time. Maybe try that cause otherwise not using Asp.Net Authorization shouldnt matter. I don't use it most times.

Comment: I've got it on top of the action each time. I will try put it on top of the controller this afternoon.

Comment: Even if I put it on top of the controller, it will not fire all the time.